# R: Multiple values in one cell, choose just 1 of them?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, in one column there are some cells where individuals could have picked multiple answers so that cell looks like: "0,2,3" for example. Like this:

```
     Answer 
1         1    
2     1,2,3    
3       1,3    
4         6    
5       1,6    
6         1
```

Based on that answer, I want to create another column with 0s and 1s. Indicating yes or no. I want the range 1-4 to be a 1 and 5-6 to be 0. If there is a mix (like a 1 and a 5), I would still like it to be a 1.

So my goal would be for it to look like:

```
     Answer     Coded
1         1         1
2     1,2,3         1
3       1,3         1
4         6         0
5       1,6         1
6         1         1
```

I am guessing the breakdown of logic would be to first break up the string, but I am stuck on how to get R to choose a certain value. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` or `grepl`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
       mutate(Coded = +(str_detect(Answer, '[1-4]')))
#   Answer Coded
#1      1     1
#2  1,2,3     1
#3    1,3     1
#4      6     0
#5    1,6     1
#6      1     1
```

---

Or using `grepl` in `base R`

```
df1$Coded <- as.integer(grepl('[1-4]', df1$Answer))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Answer = c("1", "1,2,3", "1,3", "6", "1,6", "1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"))
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I will accept it as the right answer when it lets me :) (5 min)

Comment: Could I ask a follow-up question? If I wanted to make a column that preserved the largest number (so if 6 is the biggest, put 6 in that column)- how could I apply this code to that?

Comment: @MarySmirnova You can do `library(tidyr);df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(Answer, convert = TRUE) %>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(Max = max(Answer)) %>% select(-rn) %>% bind_cols(df1, .)`

Answer (score 1):

Many different ways of doing this. One flexible option would be to create a function to get the code for each Answer. The code below works, though can probably be improved upon:

```
library(tidyverse)

coded <- function(x)
  as.integer(max(map(str_split(x, ",")[1], as.integer)[[1]]) > 4)

coded <- Vectorize(coded)
  
tibble(Answer = c("1,2,3")) %>% 
  mutate(Coded = coded(Answer))
```